# given N numbers show those above the average of the numbers themselves. C( how can i print output in main())

Tags: c

I want to know how  can i print output in main().

User gives `n` number after I declare the array, and after I pass it by address to load it, then I pass it again  address  for elaboration but I don't know to print the output in the main function.

The output is in `void elaborazionedati(int num,int vet[])`

**My Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


//Prototipo 
void caricamentovettore(int num,int vet[]);
void elaborazionedati(int num,int vet[]);
//fine

int main()
{
    //Dichiarazione variabili
    int n;
    int scelta;
    do
    {
    //how many numbers do u want to give?
    printf("---------------------\nQunati numeri vuole inserire \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    //dichiaro il vettore

    int vet[n];
    caricamentovettore(n,vet);//array load
    elaborazionedati(n,vet);// data elaboration


// this you can skip 
    printf("Per fare un'altro calcalcolo inserire :1\naltrimenti per uscire premere qualsiasi tasto\n");
    scanf("%d",&scelta);

    } while(scelta==1);
system("pause");
return 0;

}
//Inzio subroutine CARICAMENTO VETTORE
void caricamentovettore(int num,int vet[])
{   //dicgiarazione variabili
    int i,z=1;

    for(i=0;i<num;i++){

        printf("Inserireil : %d numero\n",z++);
        scanf("%d",&vet[i]);
    }
}
//fine subroutine

//here is output
//Inzio subroutine ELABORAZIONE
void elaborazionedati(int num,int vet[])
{
    int totale,media,i;
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){

        totale+=vet[i];
    }

    media=totale/num;

    for(i=0;i<num;i++){

        if(vet[i]>media){
            printf("\nI numeri maggiore alla media%d\n",vet[i])//<--------how i can print this in main?
        }
    }

}
//fine subroutine
```

so i want to know how  can i print output in main()

Comment: "*`how i can print this in main`*" did you try anything?

Comment: i started learning c this years so i dont have that knowledge  .. i tried all i know

Comment: as same as you are printing in `void elaborazionedati(int num,int vet[])`.

Comment: As a beginner you should learn that you *must always* check the return value from scanf, as with `if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) { /* could not read n */ } else { /* use n */ }`

Comment: @jackjay i know that but my teacher said in the main i have to only print the ouput without any elaboration or condition

Comment: @jens alright i know that ..forgot it thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following changes in your code,

**1** `void caricamentovettore(int num,int vet[]);` change this to `int caricamentovettore(int num,int vet[]);`

**2** remove `elaborazionedati(n,vet);` from your main function.And change `caricamentovettore(n,vet);` to `int avg = caricamentovettore(n,vet);`

**3** change `caricamentovettore` function to,

```
 void caricamentovettore(int num,int vet[])
 {   //dicgiarazione variabili
   int i,media = 0;

   for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        printf("Inserireil : %d numero\n",z++);
        scanf("%d",&vet[i]);
        media += vet[i];
     }

   return media/i;
 }
```

**4** Add this after `caricamentovettore` function call add below code,

```
 for(int i=0;i<num;i++){

    if(vet[i]>avg){
        printf("\nI numeri maggiore alla media%d\n",vet[i])//<--------how i can print this in main?
    }
}
```